# Linux server application for receiving and distributing streaming video to clients?

Tags: video, web-server

The setup I am looking for resembles the picture below:

[image]

In summary:

- A live video feed is captured by a camera which is connected to a computer.
- The computer is connected to the Internet via a connection that averages ≈ 700 Kbps. The video feed is uploaded to the server pictured on the right.
- The server then makes the video feed available to a number of web-connected clients. (The server's Internet connection exceeds 100 Mbps.)

My requirements for such an application include:

- The computer connected to the camera can run either Windows or a common Linux distribution.
- The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
- Clients will be running Windows, OS X, Linux, Android, and iOS. Support for other platforms (such as BlackBerry or Windows Mobile) is a bonus.

I have tried installing [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) on the server, but it seems like I would have to write my own Java application in order to interface with the computer providing the video feed. In addition, the documentation was absolutely terrible.

Is there a Linux tool in existence that simplifies all of this and encodes video in a supported format for the devices listed above?

Comment: The only thing I get in mind is [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net/). It has everything you require:

[image]

- [Webcam/Camera/Capture Card Input](http://www.flumotion.net/images/thumbnail-flu-source.png)
- [Seperate Front and Back Ends](http://www.flumotion.net/images/thumbnail-flu-authenticate.png)
- Anything like VLC can play it as it is an HTTP Stream. Hence, it's cross platform
- Server can run Ubuntu

No, I have not used this software personally

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Did you use this tool? What are your experiences? Is it easy to maintain / install? Does it have a good coding base? Have a look at this [High-quality answer description](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLC to stream it over http and anything that can read a stream over http can view it, you can even make a simple http5 viewer for it and run it on any device that came out in the last 5 years.

[image: Step 1]

If you want audio as well, you can select an audio device, it doesn't work with pulse sadly.
[image: Step 2]

After hitting the Stream button:
[image: Step 3]

Choose http and click add:
[image: Step 4a]

Select the port you want it to listen on and a path, usually `/stream.mp4` or `/stream.flv`, YMMV:
[image: Step 4b]

Select the encoding you want, x264/aac is usually supported but you can mess with it:
[image: Step 5]

And yes, I've personally used that setup before.